# Best practice for avoiding namespace collision and initialization functions testing Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, jasmine

What is the best thing to do to avoid name collision between development/production environment and testing environment for ember based application.

Usually, every Ember application has a namespace :

```
window.MyApp = Em.Application.create();
```

in production, I run some initialization functions by redefining the ready property of Em.Application

```
window.MyApp = Em.Application.create(

    ready: function() {
      // create some objects
    }
);
```

But, in my test enviroment, I don't want to run these initialization functions because I create objects myself. Using the same definition of MyApp causes a collision because objects I create insert the same element in the DOM. So how can I use the same namespace MyApp without the ready function when I test my application ? I use jasmine to test the application.

Comment: @MikeAski What do you mean ? I always vote for an answer when I find it interesting!

Comment: @MikeAski sorry, I'm relatively new to stackoverflow. I'll try to do my best next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep the glue code which instantiates my controllers, creates and setups views out of the `Application#ready` function.

Take [pangratz/ember.js-dashboard](https://github.com/pangratz/ember.js-dashboard/tree/dev/app/lib) for an example: `core.js` holds just the `Namespace` definitiion, whereas `controllers.js`, `views.js` and so on define my classes. The glue code which instantiates the controllers, creates the views and setups the bindings is defined in `main.js`. The `main.js` is then used among the others in the 'real' application in the `index.html`.

I use [interline/ember-skeleton](https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton) for the basic application layout, which itself uses QUnit for testing. But this should be applicable for Jasmine too.